# Work with, and debug SPEmailEventReceiver

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, event-receivers

Working first with the `SPEmailEventReceiver` ,I have created the one event receiver.

How can I debug the `SPEmailEventReceiver`?

Please provide the configuration details on the `SPEmailEventReceiver` and how to hit to the `EmailReceived` (debugging of the Event Receiver)

Below is the code snippet which I have created.

```
public class SRMMailProcessor : SPEmailEventReceiver
{
    public override void EmailReceived(SPList list, SPEmailMessage emailMessage, String receiverData)
    {
        base.EmailReceived(list, emailMessage, receiverData);
    }
}
```

Comment: The events run within the web service so you need to attach to w3wp.exe to debug.

Comment: No Tarun we need to attach OWSTimer

Answer (score 2):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/malag/2009/05/13/attachments-disappear-with-custom-email-event-handler/

Follow these steps

1. Deploy your solution to SharePoint.
2. Press Windows+R and run  Services.msc, Restart SharePoint Timer Service
3. Go back to visual studio attach process OWSTIMER.EXE and try sending mail to document library/list

NOTE: you will have to stop and start SharePoint Timer Service every time you deploy solution to SharePoint.

When you send email check the drop folder (C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop) does the mail gets stuck there?

Comment: Thanks Tarun But I am having one issue As I start debug, debugger came but, SPList getting null in the EmailRecieved method. Please Help